# Converting an if code into forloop statement

Tags: for-loop, tostring, bluej

Right now i have to write a code that will print out "*" for each collectedDots, however if it doesn't collect any collectedDots==0 then it print out "". Using too many if statements look messy and i was wandering how you would implement the forloop in this case.

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle the kind of rearrangement you've done here is good. You have found a way to express the rule in a general way rather than as a sequence of special cases. This is much easier to reason about and to check, and it's obviously extensible to cases where you have more than 3 dots.

You probably have made an error in confusing your target number and the iteration value, I assume that collectedDots contains the number of dots you have (as per your if statement) and so you need to introduce a variable to count up to that value

```
for (int i =0; i <= collectedDots; i++)
{
    stars = "*";
    System.out.print(stars);

}
```

Comment: The program that's using to check whether my code work says stars = "" is not being printed for no collected dots

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you already have a variable called collectedDots that is a number which tells you how many stars to print?

So your loop would be something like

```
for every collected dot
   print *
```

But you can't just print it out, you need to return a string that will be printed out. So it's more like

```
for every collected dot
   add a * to our string

return the string
```

They key difference between this and your attempt so far is that you were assigning a star to be your string each time through the loop, then at the end of it, you return that string–no matter how many times you assign a star to the string, the string will always just be one star.

You also need a separate variable to keep track of your loop, this should do the trick:

```
String stars = "";

for(int i = 0; i < collectedDots; i++)
{
   stars = stars + "*";
}

return stars;
```

Comment: Oh wow, that makes complete sense now, still slowly trying to understand the for loops statement properly! thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 0):

You are almost correct. Just need to change range limit of looping. Looping initial value is set to 1. So whenever you have collectedDots = 0, it will not go in loop and will return "", as stars is intialized with "" before loop.

```
String stars = "";
for (int i =1; i <= collectedDots; i++)
{
    stars = "*";
    System.out.print(stars);
}
return stars;
```